# Why am I unable to download https from server Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized. issuer: CN=Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate

On a client I'm able to access a website but not from a server, there I get this:

```
curl -v https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com
* About to connect() to objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 146.112.240.206...
* Connected to objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com (146.112.240.206) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com,O="Cisco Systems, Inc.",L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Dec 12 13:23:10 2020 GMT
*   expire date: Dec 17 13:23:10 2020 GMT
*   common name: objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com
*   issuer: CN=Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA dfw-SG,O=Cisco
* NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
* Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

or with newer curl

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a "man in the middle" firewall.  Normally it would say the issuer for that URL is "Oracle" but suspiciously it says "Cisco".  My corporate firewall is intercepting calls and redirecting them to add a tag before finally allowing them to work (which they do).  Or it maybe intercepting them to show a "blocked/malware" page.

It was working from my local computer because it was "company issued" and they had manually installed the cisco CA which apparently isn't a common, or standard browser accepted one.

Fix for me was to download the "umbrella" CA from here:

https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227987007-Block-Page-Errors-Installing-the-Cisco-Umbrella-Root-CA#CERT

and use that instead on the server:

```
 curl --cacert cisco_umbrella.cer https://somewebpage
```

(or add it in the system to your trusted CA certs).

Also weird is that it appears the firewall intercepted some https requests but not others.

(if you've set your DNS to point to opendns servers apparently can might get this issue too)

Other sightings:

https://github.com/neherlab/covid19_scenarios/issues/516

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cert-is-suddenly-different-as-seen-in-browser-from-remote/87283

https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/f8cvq7/ubuntu_server_cannot_verify_certificate_issued_by/